# Use java 8 features (newer janino version) in pentaho data integration

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, janino

Pentaho Data Integration 8.0.x is using Janino 2.5.16, released in 2010 for compiling the User Defined Java Class step. There is a [JIRA](https://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-16772) in pentaho for updating this to use a newer Janino version which would bring new java 8 related features in pentaho v8.2.0 GA. But there is no info on when will this be released.

Is there any other way I can use a newer janino version (janino-3.0.8.jar) with exiting pentaho for UDJC? I tried to copy updated jar in the lib and also added commons-compiler-3.0.8.jar to fulfill dependency. Now when I open Spoon, I get the following error:

[image: error image]

Please advise on how this can be achieved. I understand that just replacing the jar may not be enough but just want if something else can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not easy. Even now, since you got ClassNotFound, public api of janino is changed. Some classes are removed some are changed. What is actual needs to update it?

If you need really complicated business logic, then create custom plugin. Documentation and tutorials are available and you can look into sources of current builtin plugins (sources are available on github).

What important new version of janino has, that old doesn't (beside java8 support)? Checkout kettle engine, look into sources of UserDefinedClass step, change code to support new janino version, test and make own build of pdi kettle, and try to send push request to maintainers of repository.

Any of this quite complicated, This plugin is builtin into engine, and you have to make own build. Own build means, you have to support it by yourself. This is non trivial, project is huge and now even bigger and continue evolving, I spent several days to make my first custom build (version of 4, was in ivy) just for purpose to know better and debug complicated cases, and it used never in production.

Maintainers of repository must have good reason to include your changes into stream, it must be well tested and it is long procedure and most probably doesn't worth it. A lots of changed since 2010, I probable have seen in release notes, new version of java already have abilities to compile at runtime.

My advice is to make you own plugin.